# What are some ways of making a game engine centered around the idea of drawing vector lines and polygons only?

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming, vector-art

I've always loved the look of games that just use simple lines and polygons for graphics. [Rez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rez) is one of my favorite games, visually. I'm a programmer and designer first and foremost, and I'm horrible at creating Actual Art, and the idea of making a game like Rez, using mostly line and polygon drawing, really appeals to me. Sort of like how a lot of programmers like to make roguelikes with minimal or ASCII art, I really like the idea of making a game just using trigonometry to draw lines in cool ways.

I've been making a game for a school project using my school's proprietary game engine. Instead of using its 3D model drawing capabilities and 2D sprite drawing capabilities, I've instead opted to make it using only the engine's "debug draw" functionality. I went so far as to create a library of functions that allow me to create "VecSprites", or collections of lines that act in the same way as sprites, both in 2D and 3D contexts. (For 3D, I do my own matrix math to calculate perspective and stuff, forgoing the engine's own 3D rendering capabilities entirely). [Here is a video of my current project in action.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqsjGJZxFEw)

Going forward though, I want to set out to create my own game engine that will allow me to make these sorts of games on my own, without using someone else's game engine. I have plenty of experience with game engine architecture, but I don't know too much about actually drawing stuff to the screen. (Whenever I made a from-scratch game project for school, someone else was in charge of the DirectX or OpenGL side of things.) I have, however, done research into the different methods of rasterizing lines and curves and such to the screen.

What I'm wondering is, if I want to set out to make my own game engine specifically for drawing only primitive lines and circles (and then extend it with classes and such to allow for functionality such as grouping lines together into shapes), where is my best bet for getting started?

In the past, I've fooled around with [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/), only to be disappointed by the fact that, currently, it is not really meant for rendering graphics in real-time on the GPU. Two years ago I made a simple game project using it, and it worked great until I ran it at 1080p, and, as it turns out, pushing 1920x1080x4 bytes to the GPU sixty times a second isn't exactly what modern computers were meant to do.

So where do I begin? I want to draw primitive lines and polygons on PCs, specifically Windows and possibly Linux, as fast as possible. I wouldn't mind having to go through the effort of creating my own systems for drawing anti-aliased lines, filled polygons, and so forth; I just want to know what my options are for doing such things.

Do I draw lines and polygons using low-level OpenGL calls, and go from there? Is it possible to pass a bunch of data containing the shapes I want do draw to a shader, and then have the shader do it? (I'm only minimally familiar with how shaders work.)

I know this question is kind of broad, but I really want to set out on this adventure to try and make this thing, and I just don't really know where to begin, at least as far as the drawing side of things is concerned.

Comment: You may want to shorten up your question by removing irrelevant details.

Comment: Hi, you don't need to do it. OpenFL already does it beautifully, using the GPU. If you want to redraw everything in software, it will simply not work for you (most likely). You can use OpenFL, draw the needed elements in advance and position them on the screen as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need 2D you can use OpenVG which is essentially the 2D counterpart of OpenGL.

official site: https://www.khronos.org/openvg/

wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVG

If you need 3D ribbons / lines integrating with a 3D scene you'll have to do line expansion yourself and draw them using a 3D API such as OpenGL or Direct3D.

Geometry shaders can do point and line expansion into thick quads/triangles on the GPU, there are many examples & tutorials on the web for this.

Search the web for "lines using geometry shaders".

One good discussion with examples: https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/smooth-thick-lines-using-geometry-shader